# how do I copy my entire linux hard drive to a USB stick?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I am trying to copy my entire / directory to my USB hard drive. it is a hard disk enclosure but when I try I get errors saying

`cp: cannot create regular file '/media/me/119EC4454534185F/home/me/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/computer:-2bbe8711.log': Invalid argument`

I am using the command

`cp -r /* /media/me/USBDRIVE`

it is formatted in NTFS.

some help anyone? Thanks!

Comment: you're causing a recursive copy too: the drive will be copied to itselves.  Why not use eg. tar?

Comment: first off, boot off a a live-disc/usb, don't try to copy a live, running system.

Comment: You might want to advise the purpose of this - There are different strategies for different purposes.  Unfortunately the "naive" strategy of just copy everything won't work because Linux has special objects which can't be copied represented as files.   If you are wanting it to get data you can exclude these directories, but if you want something you can restore as a Linux partition you probably want to copy the whole filesystem as to a file.     Also, what is the output of 'sudo pvs; sudo lvs'  (This looks to see if you have an LVM filesystem - LVS can be useful here)